# Highest reputation in single day

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, answers

I would like to know the answer on the below questions.

1. How can I determine who has the highest reputation in a single day?
2. Who has scored highest reputation in a single day in history?
3. I know that we can see reputation leader of week/month/quarter/year/all time in [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow). Why can we not see the leader of single day?
4. Why they have make the search feature like this?

I know about [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). I don't want to use it. Is there any possible way without using it?

Comment: The [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) is your friend.

Comment: How up to date do you want this?

Comment: I want to know how can i achieve this? is there any way without DdataExplorer?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Data. SE? That's what it's for...

Comment: You can only get a maximum of 200 reputation in a single day. Therefore the answer is: Lots of people get highest reputation in a single day. (Unless bounty awards get handled differently, I'm not sure).

Comment: @JonW No, you can get much more. Question accept (15 rep points) are for example immune from the rep cap.

Comment: I think I've got 335 in one day... 20 upvotes and 9 accepts - but no bounties on top - so I could imagine, a 1000 is perfectly plausible if a couple of bounties fell on the same day...

Comment: @NullPointer: Ah I see, so in that case the answer to OPs questions are - 1)Look at Jon Skeets history. 2)Jon Skeet 3)Jon Skeet recursive 4)just go to Jon Skeet's profile.

Comment: I've once reached 947 in a single day on SO. I however recall having seen someone going over 1K with 2 high-rep bounties awarded the same day. Not sure who it was. Something with "Gomez" in the name? And here on meta.SO, due to some bug I've a (incorrect) peak of 1154 in my graph :(

Comment: OP, can you explain why you "don't want to use" the data explorer ?

Comment: @Chichiray: that would be [MrGomez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/517815/mrgomez?tab=reputation&sort=graph), 1225 in a single day.

Comment: Yes, that was him :) He went really on a bounty spree that period.

Comment: I think my highest in a day *without* bounties is 650 (September 28th 2011). I believe others have done better, very occasionally. Including bounties, my highest is 870 (so far lower than MrGomez).

Comment: @JonSkeet - But your average is just awesome and unbeatable. :(

Comment: @hims056: It certainly helps that the last time I *didn't* hit the rep cap was June 2010 :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - OMG. I want to see your reputation summary via http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @hims056 .... i want to get knowledge like him in one year ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is achievable from anywhere.
Because

1. There is no such option either in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or in [Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow)
2. There is no table for Reputation in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (IMO it's not public).

We can't see daily reputation leader but we can see reputation leader of week/month/quarter/year/all time in [Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow)

Comment: @him056: thats exactly i am talking about. why they have make it like this? if we are able to know leader of week/month/year than why dnt of single day? i knew what you have written as answer.

Comment: @Bhavesh - *Why don't of single day?* because of time difference in all over the world.

Comment: @hims056 yes, a day is a day from UTC on SO - not a 24 hour shifting period...

Comment: @hims056: sory but i do not agree with you fully. cz if that would be problem then it would also be hurdle for week/month/year.

Comment: You can get reputation (aggregate) from the data explorer, but not in the way you'd need to do a query for this.

Comment: @TimPost - To do a query we need a table where we can separate reputation somehow. Also, we don't get nagetive reputation (for downvoting) of any user.